# What would be a good API design with two identifiers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, curl

I am not quite sure what would be a good API design for my scenario below.

We have a model ticket that has an ID and a QR code, both of which are always unique.

To query the status of a ticket, I'm sure this should look obviously like this:

```
GET /tickets/:id
```

But what should the design of the QR code API look like?
By also using GET /tickets/:id it would be unclear to the user which locator is being searched for.

```
GET /tickets?qr_code=:qr_code
```

would be the second option, but I find this so unpleasant because the returned element is always exactly one and not an array which usually would be the expected response of such a request.

How would a proper API design look like here to query the status of a single ticket by its QR code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple attributes that are unique then that means that each attribute can serve as an identifier in the URL.

Therefore I would document the route in the API like this

```
GET /tickets/:id_or_qr_code
```

What basically boils down to the default resource path

```
GET /tickets/:id
```

with a controller method like this

```
def show
  @ticket = Ticket.find_by(id: params[:id]) || 
            Ticket.find_by(qr_code: params[:id]) || 
  # ...
end
```

Comment: @Fabio if you prefer one over the other, you could also respond with a 3xx redirect.